# t:DataTable throws Not Serializable Exception

Tags: java, jsf, tomahawk

I am using `JSF 2.0` with `tomahawk 2.0` and `websphere v8.5`. I am getting an error with `t:dataTable` when ever i fill values from database it throws an exception `java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.myfaces.component.html.ext.HtmlDataTable` my backing beans `implements serialization` and it is `@ViewScope`

```
public class Templates implements Serializable
{
... 
}
```

faces-config.xml

```
<managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>templates </managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>cms.Templates</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Comment: Post the full stacktrace here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem ref : [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/myfaces-users/200601.mbox/%3CW709608949286571137271145@webmail8%3E), Since the class was serialized and `HtmlDataTable` is variable of class that should not be serialized so just i have to make this `transient`